# Check mutiple values in Array and append third value in html

Tags: jquery, html, json

I want to check if mutiple vlaues exists in the array, and if they do, append the value of a third one- the script below obvously doesnt work, but might give a good idea on what I want to do. i only want to add this once, even if the array checks several times.

What's the best way to do this?

```js
var names = {
  list: [{
      "model": "round",
      "type": "Special",
      "typedescription": "appendedvalue"
    }, {
      "model": "round",
      "type": "Special",
      "typedescription": "appendedvalue",
    }
    "model": "round",
    "type": "Special",
    "typedescription": "appendedvalue"
  },
  {
    "model": "square",
    "type": "Special",
    "typedescription": "appendedvalue"
  }]

};

if ($.inArray('model.round', 'type.special'
    names) !== -1) {
  $('.test').append('<p>' + typedescription.appendedvalue + '</p>');
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: *append the value of a third one* Which third one? Do you mean, in this case, the third occurrence of an object with both `model: round` and `type: Special`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes. If the array has  both round and special, i want to append the value of typedescription. Sorry if this was not clear.

Comment: Which `typedescription`? The third one with those properties in the array, or are they all the same (so any of them)?

Comment: @CertainPerfomance The one with the properties in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.find` to try to find a matching object. Put the test (of whether the object has the `model` and `type` you want) in the callback. If it exists, append the property:

```js
var names = {
  list: [{
      "model": "round",
      "type": "Special",
      "typedescription": "appendedvalue"
    }, {
      "model": "round",
      "type": "Special",
      "typedescription": "appendedvalue",
    }, {
    "model": "round",
    "type": "Special",
    "typedescription": "appendedvalue"
  },
  {
    "model": "square",
    "type": "Special",
    "typedescription": "appendedvalue"
  }]

};

const item = names.list.find(({ model, type }) => model === 'round' && type === 'Special');
if (item) {
  $('.test').append('<p>' + item.typedescription + '</p>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Is it possible tp  do this without Arrows? this gives me a ES6 error :)

Comment: If your environment doesn't even support ES2015, you should consider upgrading it - ES2015 came out many years ago, which is an eternity in web development terms. The best professional strategy is to write code in the latest and greatest version of the language, then use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and polyfills in production so that obsolete browsers can understand the code.

Comment: Doing it manually, to translate an arrow function to a non-arrow function, put `function` instead (and, in the case of a concise body, `return`), and don't destructure: `.find(function(item) { return item.model === 'round' && item.type === 'Special' })`

Comment: @CertainPerfomance - Im loading this trough Google Tag Manager, that doesnt allow the arrow function. This works though - and thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = {
  list: [
    {
      "model": "round",
      "type": "Special",
      "typeDescription": "appendedvalue"
    },
    {
      "model": "round",
      "type": "Special",             
      "typeDescription": "appendedvalue",
    },
    {
      "model": "round",
      "type": "Special",
      "typeDescription": "appendedvalue"
    },
    {
      "model": "square",
      "type": "Special",
      "typeDescription": "appendedvalue"
    }
  ]
};

let name = names
  .list
  .find(n => n.model === "round" && n.type === "Special");

if(name) {
  $('.test').append(`<p>${name.typeDescription}</p>`);
}
```